2 Disks Suddenly Showing as Spares on Raid 5 Array
I have a raid5 array in a Seagate Blackarmor 440 nas that suddenly started showing disks 1 and 4 as "failed". I moved all of the drives over to a Ubuntu box and tried to assemble the array with mdadm. Long story short, here's where I'm at.
It looks like Seagate creates a raid partition for the fs, swap, hard reset files, and finally data. The fs, swap, and "hard reset files" are in raid 1, but the data was in 5. If I do an mdadm --assemble --scan I get
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 4 drives.
mdadm: /dev/md1 has been started with 3 drives (out of 4).
mdadm: /dev/md2 has been started with 3 drives (out of 4).

where md0 is the filesystem, md1 is swap, and md2 is reset stuff, but md3 doesn't come up.
The drives seem fine, just seem to have the wrong slot assignment (-1)
sudo mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md3 /dev/sd[abcd]4 --verbose --force
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md3
mdadm: /dev/sda4 is identified as a member of /dev/md3, slot -1.
mdadm: /dev/sdb4 is identified as a member of /dev/md3, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdc4 is identified as a member of /dev/md3, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdd4 is identified as a member of /dev/md3, slot -1.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 0 of /dev/md3
mdadm: added /dev/sdb4 to /dev/md3 as 2
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 3 of /dev/md3
mdadm: added /dev/sda4 to /dev/md3 as -1
mdadm: added /dev/sdd4 to /dev/md3 as -1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc4 to /dev/md3 as 1
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md3: Input/output error
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.

cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md3 : inactive sdb4[2](S) sdc4[1](S) sdd4[4](S) sda4[0](S)
      7802831488 blocks super 1.2

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[2] sdc3[1]
      521408 blocks [4/3] [UUU_]

md1 : inactive sdd2[3](S) sdc2[1](S) sda2[0](S) sdb2[2](S)
      4179200 blocks

md0 : active raid1 sdc1[1] sdd1[3] sda1[0] sdb1[2]
      1043840 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>

is there a way to tell mdadm what order to build the array in?
